# Entity Framework Code first adds unwanted foreign key column

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have a many to one relationship between **Categories** and **News**.

The problem I'm having is that EF keeps adding a foreign key colum to my table which I dont want!

**News class**

```
public class News
{
    public News()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    public int NewsID { get; set; }

    public int PublishedByID { get; set; }
    public string PublishedByFullName { get; set; }
    public string PublishedByEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PreviewText { get; set; }

    public string BlobName { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

**Categories class**

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        News = new HashSet<News>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CategoryTypeName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

**Database**

[image: Database]

**My question**

How do I remove **Category_CategoryID** in **News** table?

I'm guessing i'm missing some code in my OnModelCreating method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add id field in `News` class to reference Category.

```
public class News
{
    [Key]
    public int NewsID { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; } // added

    public int PublishedByID { get; set; }
    public string PublishedByFullName { get; set; }
    public string PublishedByEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PreviewText { get; set; }

    public string BlobName { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Aha okey. So im actually forced to have a foreign key colum? (dumb question).

Comment: @Reft In database table - yes.